# Calculating the iterated integral of a piecewise function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Let $f(x,y)$ be defined as follows:

[image]

I want to calculate $\int_0^1 \int_0^1 f(x,y) dxdy$ and $\int_0^1 \int_0^1 f(x,y) dydx$, and to show that they're not equal. I'm not even sure where to begin - I've done piecewise integrals before, but none where the domains depend on some variable $n$. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the regions are rectangles, so the integrals are straightforward:

$$\int_0^1 dy \, \int_0^1 dx \, f(x,y) = 2^{2 n} \int_{2^{-n}}^{2^{-(n-1)}} dy \, \int_{2^{-n}}^{2^{-(n-1)}} dx - 2^{2 n+1} \int_{2^{-n}}^{2^{-(n-1)}} dy \, \int_{2^{-(n+1)}}^{2^{-n}} dx $$

$$\int_0^1 dx \, \int_0^1 dy \, f(x,y) = 2^{2 n} \int_{2^{-n}}^{2^{-(n-1)}} dx \, \int_{2^{-n}}^{2^{-(n-1)}} dy - 2^{2 n+1} \int_{2^{-(n+1)}}^{2^{-n}} dx \,  \int_{2^{-n}}^{2^{-(n-1)}} dy  $$

Not seeing how these are not equal.